# Dynamic amount of custom tableviewcell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableview controller with 3 different custom cells.

The first cell will be the first to display in the tableview followed by the second cell. I'm able to set the first cell by checking if `indexPath.row == 0`. However for the second cell, it can be either 2 or more to be populated.

I'm unable to use `indexPath.row` to check for the row to populate as the row number will be different

After populating the second cell, the third cell will be populated at the end of the tableview.

I have one more question, I'm able to set the label text value by using `Cell2.textLabel.text = "Hello Word"`. But if I have a text field in the cell, how can I get the value of the text from each of the cell?

Comment: Have you considered using a Header and a Footer for your 2 cells that appear first and last?

Comment: But if I got 4 different custom cells it would not be feasible

Comment: Ok what are you trying to achieve ? Show some code or give a little context

Comment: It's something like a form. The first cell have a label and the last cell to have a button. One of the custom cell will be a cell with textfield inside. I might have another cell with a slider. The amount cell that I want to display depends on the backend. I might require 4 different textfield cell and 2 slider cell.

Comment: For first cell you should check `if indexPath.row==0` and the last one(with the button) is `formFields.count+1` (plus one as you already inserted the first extra cell).

There are various methods for identifying the `UITextField` in cells. You could for example use `UITextFieldDelegate` set to the VC and set the `textField.tag= indexPath.row`